# Vue - add class to parent LI from child component in iterated list?

Tags: loops, vue.js, indexing

What's the best way to add a class to the parent li in an iterated list, from a `<LiComponent>`?

parent component

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in List" class="" :key="`li_${i}`"> // waiting for child to add active
      <ChildLiComponent :key="`child_${i}`" :index="i" @addActiveClass="handleActiveClass" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleActiveClass() {
      // not sure here...
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

child LI component

```html
<template>
  <button @click="setActive">
    Add class 'active' to my parent
  </button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['props'],
  methods: {
    setActive() {
      this.$emit('addActiveClass', this.i);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want one active class at a time, in your parent component, add a data property to track the active item

```js
data: () => ({
  activeItem: null,
  List: [] // whatever
})
```

In your `ChildLiComponent`, you can emit an event to signal the activation

```js
setActive () {
  this.$emit('add-active-class') // note the event name casing
}
```

and handle this in your parent template with a class-binding on the `<li>`

```html
<li v-for="(item, i) in List" :class="{ active: activeItem === item }" :key="`li_${i}`">
  <ChildLiComponent :key="`child_${i}`" @add-active-class="activeItem = item" />
</li>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with `item`. It's undefined in parent. Do I need a handler method in the parent?

Comment: Sorry @KirkRoss, I'm not sure what you mean. `item` is defined in the `v-for`.

Comment: ahh... my bad, I had changed it to item for this example because my real code is oddly named. Thanks.